# Kotlin, Android Studio: I can't get my program to use a second adapter. List Views

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I'm relatively new to programing on Kotlin, with Android Studio, and I'm currently developing some issues with my List Views.

I'm currently following [this tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/155-android-listview-tutorial-with-kotlin), and having made some changes managed to make it work for my program, even though it is focused to get data from a JSON file and I'm getting it from Firestore.

I have my data read from Firestore database. Firstly I read it to make a list of restaurants (documents) from my area, which I have no problem with. But as soon as I try to create another list based on the data from those restaurants (documents), such as categories of products on their menus (Drinks, Salads, Burgers, etc.), I am unable to get anything shown on screen, even though I'm using exactly the same methods and adapters on this new class.

This is the code I use from the first class, in which I get the list properly displayed:

```
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.ListView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.al.tfmteleco.utiles.AdaptadorListaEstablecimientos
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore


val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()


class Explorar : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var listView: ListView
    private val establecimientosList = ArrayList<ModelEstablecimientos>()
    private var establecimiento: ModelEstablecimientos? = null
    private var IDEstablecimiento: Int? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_explorar)

        listView = findViewById<ListView>(R.id.listaEstablecimientos)
// 1
        getEstablecimientos()

        listView.setOnItemClickListener{_,_,position,_ ->
            finish()
            establecimiento = establecimientosList[position]
            IDEstablecimiento = establecimiento!!.ID

            println("La ID es: $IDEstablecimiento")
            val intent = Intent(this@Explorar, Establecimiento::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("establecimientoID", IDEstablecimiento.toString())
            startActivity(intent)

        }
    }

    private fun getEstablecimientos() {

        db.collection("establecimientos")
            .get()
            .addOnSuccessListener { result ->
                for (document in result) {
                    establecimientosList.add(
                        ModelEstablecimientos(
                            document.getString("Nombre"),
                            document.getString("Categoria1"),
                            document.getString("Categoria2"),
                            document.getString("Categoria3"),
                            document.getString("Precio"),
                            document.getString("Localizacion"),
                            document.getLong("MesasDisponibles")?.toInt(),
                            document.getLong("MesasOcupadas")?.toInt(),
                            document.getLong("Abierto")?.toInt(),
                            document.getLong("PuntosOpiniones")?.toFloat(),
                            document.getLong("OpinionesTotales")?.toInt(),
                            document.id.toInt()
                        )
                    )

                    Log.d("Documentos", "${document.id} => ${document.data}")

// 2
                    val listItems = arrayOfNulls<String>(establecimientosList.size)
// 3
                    for (i in 0 until establecimientosList.size) {
                        val establecimiento = establecimientosList[i]
                        listItems[i] = establecimiento.nombre
                    }
// 4
                    val adapter =
                        AdaptadorListaEstablecimientos(
                            this,
                            establecimientosList
                        )
                    listView.adapter = adapter
                }
            }
            .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
                Log.d("Documentos", "Error getting documents: ", exception)
            }

    }
}
```

This one is from the Adapter Class, used for that List.

```
import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.Color
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.*
import com.al.tfmteleco.ModelEstablecimientos
import com.al.tfmteleco.R


class AdaptadorListaEstablecimientos(private val context: Context,
    private val dataSource: ArrayList<ModelEstablecimientos>) : BaseAdapter() {

    private val inflater: LayoutInflater
            = context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater

    //1
    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return dataSource.size
    }

    //2
    override fun getItem(position: Int): Any {
        return dataSource[position]
    }

    //3
    override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
        return position.toLong()
    }

    //4
    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
        // Get view for row item
        val rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lista_establecimientos, parent, false)
        // Get title element
        val nombreTextView = rowView.findViewById(R.id.nombreEstablecimiento) as TextView

        // Get cat1 element
        val cat1TextView = rowView.findViewById(R.id.cat1Establecimiento) as TextView

        // Get cat1 element
        val cat2TextView = rowView.findViewById(R.id.cat2Establecimiento) as TextView

        // Get cat1 element
        val cat3TextView = rowView.findViewById(R.id.cat3Establecimiento) as TextView

        // Get rangoprecio element
        //val rangoprecioTextView = rowView.findViewById(R.id.precioEstablecimiento) as TextView

        // Get mapa element
        val mapaButton = rowView.findViewById(R.id.mapaEstablecimiento) as ImageView

        // Get mesas element
        val mesasTextView = rowView.findViewById(R.id.mesasEstablecimiento) as TextView

        // Get mensaje element
        val mensajeTextView = rowView.findViewById(R.id.mensajeEstablecimiento) as TextView

        // Get info element
        val infoButton = rowView.findViewById(R.id.infoEstablecimiento) as ImageView

        // Get points element
        val ptsTextView = rowView.findViewById(R.id.ptsOpinion) as TextView
        val ratingBarView = rowView.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar) as RatingBar

// 1
        val listaEstablecimientos = getItem(position) as ModelEstablecimientos

// 2
        nombreTextView.text = listaEstablecimientos.nombre                  // NOMBRE DEL ESTABLECIMIENTO
        cat1TextView.text = listaEstablecimientos.cat1                      // CATEGORIA 1 DEL ESTABLECIMIENTO
        cat2TextView.text = listaEstablecimientos.cat2                      // CATEGORIA 2 DEL ESTABLECIMIENTO
        cat3TextView.text = listaEstablecimientos.cat3                      // CATEGORIA 3 DEL ESTABLECIMIENTO


// LOCALIZACIÓN DEL ESTABLECIMIENTO
        if(listaEstablecimientos.loc == null){
            mapaButton.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        }
            else{
            mapaButton.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }

// MESAS DISPONIBLES DEL ESTABLECIMIENTO
        mesasTextView.text = listaEstablecimientos.mesasOcupadas.toString() +
                "/" +
                listaEstablecimientos.mesasDisponibles.toString() + " mesas ocupadas"
        var mesasO : Float = listaEstablecimientos.mesasOcupadas!!.toFloat()
        var mesasD : Float = listaEstablecimientos.mesasDisponibles!!.toFloat()
        if (mesasO/mesasD <= 0.2){
            mesasTextView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#2D6E30"))
        }
            else if (mesasO/mesasD <= 0.6){
            mesasTextView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#D14F00"))
        }
            else if (mesasO/mesasD >= 0.85){
            mesasTextView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#8A0000"))
        }

// ESTADO DEL ESTABLECIMIENTO
        if(listaEstablecimientos.mensaje == 0){
            mensajeTextView.text = "Cerrado"
            mensajeTextView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#8A0000"))
        }
            else if(listaEstablecimientos.mensaje == 1){
            mensajeTextView.text = "Abierto"
            mensajeTextView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#2D6E30"))
        }

// PUNTUACIÓN DEL LOCAL POR PARTE DE LOS USUARIOS
        var puntos : Float = listaEstablecimientos.puntos!!.toFloat()
        var opiniones : Float = listaEstablecimientos.opiniones!!.toFloat()

        // Formato para mostrar el número con un solo decimal
        var pts= "%.${1}f".format(puntos/opiniones).toFloat()

        ptsTextView.text = pts.toString()
        ratingBarView.rating = pts


// Si la posición del establecimiento en la lista es par, el fondo es algo más oscuro
        if(position % 2 == 0){
            rowView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#E8E8E8"))
        }

        return rowView
    }
}
```

"So well, if it works, just try to adapt it" - I thought. And I tried, it should be even simplier, as I just had to use a standard list pattern, with just one item (the category name) on the list. For some reason, it doesn't work. It reads the data fine, but it cannot get to adapt another list, it seems.

This is the code I'm using and in which I'm finding trouble:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter
import android.widget.ListView

class Categorias : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var listViewCategorias: ListView
    private val categoriasList = ArrayList<ModelCategorias>()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_categorias)
        listViewCategorias = findViewById(R.id.listaCategorias)

        val establecimientoID=intent.getStringExtra("establecimientoID")
        println(establecimientoID)
        getCategorias(establecimientoID.toInt())

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_categorias)
    }

    private fun getCategorias(ID:Int) {

        db.collection("establecimientos").document(ID.toString()).collection("categorias")
            .get()
            .addOnSuccessListener { result ->
                for (document in result) {
                    categoriasList.add(
                        ModelCategorias(
                            document.getString("Nombre_Categoria"),
                            document.id.toInt()
                        )
                    )

                    Log.d("Categorias", "${document.id} => ${document.data}")

// 2
                    val listItems = arrayOfNulls<String>(categoriasList.size)
// 3
                    for (i in 0 until categoriasList.size) {
                        val categoria = categoriasList[i]
                        listItems[i] = categoria.nombreCategoria.toString()
                        println(listItems[i].toString())
                    }

                    val adapter = ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listItems)

                    listViewCategorias.adapter = adapter
                }
            }
            .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
                Log.d("Documentos", "Error getting documents: ", exception)
            }
    }
}
```

I'm very sorry for this very long first post, but I'm rather desperate. Excuse me for my rusty English as well.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "it cannot get to adapt another list"? Compile error, crash with a stack trace, something else?

Comment: It operates properly with the ArrayList, as the println() works fine, but it doesn't crash, shows any error or any kind of warning, it just doesn't display the list as it should once I try the App.

Comment: So the list is completely blank? I don't see anything wrong in the above code, except that you're creating the adapter inside your loop, so you are creating multiple useless adapters, and only the last one is actually used. But that wouldn't prevent it from showing your data.

Comment: Yes, the ArrayList called `categoriasList` is filled properly, but the ListView object, which has to show that data on screen, isn't working as in the first piece of code.

Thank you for the input on the loop issue though, I'll have a look and try to make it more efficient :)

Answer (score 0):

Activity where it's working:

val adapter = AdaptadorListaEstablecimientos(this, establecimientosList)

---

Activity where it's not working:

val adapter = ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listItems)

If ArrayAdapter and AdaptadorListaEstablecimientos are basically the same adapter it shouldn't be needing an extra property (in this case, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1). You should take a further look into the differences between the adapters.

Comment: It's the difference between a custom Adapter and the provided ArrayAdapter. No reason to expect them to have the same constructor parameters. The custom adapter is designed for a specific list item layout, so it doesn't need one to be passed to its constructor.

Comment: Sure, but if they're wondering why one works and the other doesn't that's where I'd look. It's entirely possible the model they're passing to the default ArrayAdapter doesn't work with the ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, T[] objects) constructor they're using.

Comment: It looks like they're using ArrayAdapter correctly, but I could have missed a detail. ArrayAdapter works with any type of object array because it simply calls `toString()` on each item. They didn't say what actually went wrong. It wouldn't affect the end results, but they should move the adapter set-up outside the for-loop to avoid creating a bunch of obsolete adapters. That's a problem in their original code as well, though.

Comment: Yeah, I'm kinda just shooting at anything that looks out of the ordinary.

Comment: I was using the same adapter before, but it didn't work either. So I changed to a simplier one, so as to see if my "new" Adapter for that Class was the issue, but it wasn't. It doesn't display the array in my activity.

Comment: Two other things to try: Casting listViewCategorias as findViewById<ListView> instead of just findViewById. Assure that categoriasList.size isn't 0. Aside from those I'm tapped on ideas.

Comment: Thank you! I'll have a try tomorrow morning :)